# Resolve reference json in js

Tags: javascript, json, jsog

how can I solve the json reference and get the object in js?

```
{
    laboratorio: {
        @id: "5", 
        version: 17, 
        idLaboratorio: 25779, 
        codLaboratorio: 30
    }
    laboratorioPedido: {@ref: "5"} 
}
```

I want something like this:

```
{
    laboratorio: {
        @id: "5", 
        version: 17, 
        idLaboratorio: 25779, 
        codLaboratorio: 30
    }
    laboratorioPedido: {
        @id: "5", 
        version: 17, 
        idLaboratorio: 25779, 
        codLaboratorio: 30
    } 
}
```

thanks

**SOLVED**

It was a JSOG object! (not JSON)

I have used this function and it works

```
cyclicGraph = JSOG.decode(jsogStructure);
```

Comment: That isn't JSON. JSON doesn't have references, and even without the reference syntax there, it wouldn't be valid JSON.

Comment: You're right! It was a jsog object. I was wrong! 
Thank you very much for the help. I have used this function and it works: `cyclicGraph = JSOG.decode(jsogStructure);`